# Quick alternative to lots of if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm  beginner at java, and I'm making a simple program where I type in something, and if what I type in matches one of the things on the "database" then it'll print some text. Is there a simpler way to check this rather than doing this:

```
int 1;
int 2;
int 3;
```

etc.

```
if([USER INPUT].equals("1")) {
    System.out.println("TEST");
}
```

400 times.

Comment: You can use a switch, or a `Map` from ints/strings/whatever to actions (`Runnable`, `Function`, etc).

Comment: Can you add a hierarchy to split the 400 commands in sub-groups?

Comment: If one of the answers answers your question then mark it as the answer.

Comment: Or add comments so people can improve their answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a switch statement or a HashMap.

Switch statement: Readable, but compiles similarly (if not identically) to an if-else chain.

```
switch([USER_INPUT]) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("TEST");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("HELLO");
        break;
    // And so on.
}
```

[Hash Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): Much more readable and simpler. This is preferred.

```
// Initialization.
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1,"TEST");
map.put(2,"HELLO");

// Printing.
String s = map.get(USER_INPUT);
if (s == null)
    System.out.println("Key doesn't exist.");
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: why is this better than an IF ?

Comment: I should elaborate on HashMaps.

Comment: @NimChimpsky it's a "Quick alternative to lots of if statements". Especially powerful over enums where it's easy to demonstrate complete coverage. Guarantees to the reader that more complex conditions like `i < 5 && length > 6` won't be used so it's not necessary to read through the cases in detail. Omitting breaks leading to fallthrough is a known problem and ideally compiler warns you about that.

Comment: The subject readbaility is the only advantage ? Use a hashmap.

Comment: @djechlin enums ? Use an enummap. switchs are just as bad as if's, imho.

Comment: @NimChimpsky no, they're not, for the reasons I just explained and you ignored. Yes, a map is better in this case since there's no difference in code, just difference in data.

Comment: @djechlin the only other reasons mentioned were complex conditions, which is not the case here; and "complete coverage" ... not sure what that means.

Comment: @NimChimpsky ...which is why I just said "a map is better in this case." okay, I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashMap, with key as Integer, and value as text.

```
System.out.println(myMap.get(USER_INPUT));
```

Where you have done `myMap.put(1, "TEST");` etc, this keeps your code much OO.

the underlying bytecode of switch and if are very comparable, and personally don't see any advantage of switching to switch (unless you want fall through, which means don't include break statement).

Answer (score 1):

A fun alternative would be to use an enum.  This would work if you want to define all of the values in a class.   It would simplify the code used to get the text value.   And it gives you some more fun options beyond what a switch statement would give you.

```
enum NumberText {
    HELLO(1),
    WORLD(2);

    private static final HashMap<Integer,NumberText> map = new HashMap<Integer,NumberText>();
    static{
        for (ConnectionGenerator c : ConnectionGenerator.values()) {
            map.put(c.code, c);
        }
    }

    Integer code;

    NumberText(Integer pCode) {
        this.code = pCode;
    }

    Static ConnectionGenerator getTextFor(Integer code) {
        return map.get(code);
    }
}
```

Then to get the text, simply do this:

```
NumberText nt = NumberText.getTextFor(USER_INPUT);
System.out.println(nt);
```

You can get fancier and put an additional constructor variable into the enum and have a specific string of text.

```
enum NumberText {
    HELLO(1, "Hello to You"),
    GOODBYE(2, "Goodbye");

    private static final HashMap<Integer,NumberText> map = new HashMap<Integer,NumberText>();
    static{
        for (ConnectionGenerator c : ConnectionGenerator.values()) {
            map.put(c.code, c);
        }
    }

    Integer code;
    String text;

    NumberText(Integer pCode, String pText) {
        this.code = pCode;
        this.text = pText;
    }

    ConnectionGenerator getNumberTextFor(Integer code) {
        return map.get(code);
    }

    getText() {
    return this.text;
}
}
```

Then you could get the text like this:

```
NumberText.getNumberTextFor(USER_INPUT).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` statement.

```
switch(i){ 
    case 1:
    System.out.println("Hi");
    break;
    case 2:
    System.out.println("Ok");
    break;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement.

Here's a quick tutorial and some more in-depth explanation.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html